# How to write this logic function with this specific logic gate?

Tags: function, boolean, logic, boolean-algebra

The problem is as follows: obtain the function **H = X + Y** using only

[image: the pictured logic gate]

You cannot use the complements of X and Y as inputs. Use as few of these logic gates as possible.

I eventually figured out the answer to be

[image: this]

but that was through trial and error. Is there a good way of solving this and similar problems?

Comment: `Y NAND NOT X` is equal to `Y TO X`, where `TO` is for material implication. `Y OR X` is equal to `(Y TO X) TO X`, right.